# Phaser Game instance error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Phaser is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I am a relatively new JS developer if you can even call me one yet, and I am trying to learn the Phaser framework. Anyway, I have what most would call the 'Basic Phaser setup' but when I run my program in the browser (Chrome) the console throws an error saying, `Uncaught ReferenceError: Phaser is not defined` on line 1 which is where I created my Phaser 'game' instance. This prevents my main code from running which is making a background tileSprite from scrolling up by 2 pixels every frame I was watching a tutorial video and I tried to mimic the video maker's code exactly but my code still won't run. I would be extremely grateful if anyone could help me out and tell me what is going wrong. Thank you!

Here is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Js Scroller</title
 <script type="text/javascript" src='phaser.min.js'></script>
 
  <script type="text/javascript" src='scrolling.js'></script>

</head>
<body>
 <style>
  
 </style>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game(800,600,Phaser.CANVAS,'gameDiv');

var starfield;

var mainState = {
 preload: function() {
  game.load.image('starfield', '/Users/wyatthume/Desktop/starfield.png');
 },

 create: function() {
  starfield = game.add.tileSprite(0,0,800,600, 'starfield');
 },

 update: function() {
  starfield.tilePosition.y += 2;
 }

}

game.state.add('mainState', mainState);
game.state.start(mainState);
```

Comment: The dev tools provide a **Network** tab. Regarding the Phaser script source, please confirm: Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested?

Comment: Also, you have an unclosed tag at `</title`.

Comment: Im sorry, but i'm not really sure were this would show up in the network tab

Comment: Are you using a variation of Phaser 2 or Phaser 3?

Answer (score 2):

Be certain that the path to Phaser can be resolved based on where your index.html.

In this case, if your index.html is in /home/foo/Web/index.html, then make sure the file /home/foo/Web/phaser.min.js exists.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very old thread but as it comes up on Google on the very first page and it is unanswered, I'll answer it. :)

Phaser is not defined because the asker has opened the HTML file directly and such, the phaser path was incorrectly read. Whenever you use a webserver, make sure you call it correctly.

Your browser should display

- `http://localhost/phaser3-tutorial-src/part3.html` (or something along this line)

but

- **NEVER C:/ D:/ E:/**

I hope this will help someone out there! Happy phasering.